# Is there pseudo-distribution mode still supported in hadoop 2.2.0?

Tags: hadoop

I was trying to run hadoop 2.2.0 on my pc in a pseudo-distribution mode. unfortunately, I couldn't find any doc about how to config a pseudo-distribution mode on hadoop 2.2.0. So I followed some tutorials about some earlier version, and it run pretty well. But I wonder if the hadoop is running on a single-node mode or  a pseudo-distribution mode. Is there any indicator to tell me about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) is the doc on how to setup single-node cluster with 2.2.0, it shares the same page as 2.1.1-beta though.

Comment: Is single-node cluster the same with pseudo-distribution?

Comment: I don't see much difference. `Hadoop can also be run on a single-node in a pseudo-distributed mode where each Hadoop daemon runs in a separate Java process.`

Comment: How can I run multiple reducers on a single-node?

Comment: man, that's a total different question. Can you please accept this one (if my answer is acceptable) and ask a new question?